# Error en directorio con Android 10 en cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap, apache-cordova

Estoy usando este script en `Cordova` para guardar un `.pdf` en una archivo  que funciona perfectamente en `Android8` , pero no sé porque me da un error en `android10`. No logro encontrar el error, tan solo el código se va al método

> onGetDirectoryFail()

```
var descargarPDF = (urlDescarga, tipoDocumento) => {

    sessionStorage.platform = 'android';
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    if (tipoDocumento == 1) {
        filename = "example1.pdf"
    }

    if (tipoDocumento == 2) {
        filename = "example2.pdf"
    }

    try {
        if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
        }
        else {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("ER - " + err.message);
    }

    function onError(e) {
        alert("onError");
    };

    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        var entry = "";
        if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
            entry = fileSystem;
        }
        else {
            entry = fileSystem.root;
        }
        entry.getDirectory("Cordava", { create: true, exclusive: false }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
    };

    function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
        dir.getDirectory("Data", { create: true, exclusive: false }, onGetDirectorySuccess1, onGetDirectoryFail);
    };

    function onGetDirectorySuccess1(dir) {
        cdr = dir;
        dir.getFile(filename, { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
    };

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
         var uri = encodeURI(urlDescarga);
       
        fileTransfer.download(uri, cdr.nativeURL + filename,
            function (entry) {
                openFile();
            },
            function (error) {
                endLoader();
                alert(" error " + error.source);
            },
            true);
    };

 //Aquí es donde se va el codigo con Android10 
  function onGetDirectoryFail(error) {
    alert("onGetDirectoryFail");
};
```

Alguna idea, por favor, de lo que estoy haciendo mal, estoy atascado en eso.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en Android ya 10 no puedes acceder a `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`

Para permitir acceder agrega en tu config.xml:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

de esta forma:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
   <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
</edit-config>
```